# Group and Game Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am thinking of an algorithm that assign games to pairs of opponents which play the game.

I have x opponents and y games (I think y should be x - 1, but I am not sure)
Every opponent should play each game once and if possible play against every opponent once.

What I want is a list of group pairings assigned to a game.
The number of games overall should be minimal.

An example with 4 opponents `A, B, C, D` and 3 games:

| Opp1 | Game | Opp2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | B |
| A | 2 | C |
| A | 3 | D |
| B | 2 | C |
| B | 3 | D |
| C | 1 | D |

Here, each opponent plays against another opponent exactly once, and every opponent plays each game exactly once.

Trying that manually for 5 opponents and 4 games already gets complex.

How about 7 opponents and 6 games?
Is that possible at all?

I tried that to solve the problem manually, then I found out that this is too complex.

After that I thought about how I could maybe solve it using an algorithm, but I could not come up with a solution.
I thought maybe a graph algorithm which tries to minimize the overall games count could help.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a 'group'  In your table C is in both groups, which is confusing

Comment: "An example with 4 groups"  You example seems to have just 2 groups!

Comment: @ravenspoint I think they mean that one group plays against another group, symmetrically. Here, A, B, C and D are the groups.

Comment: @Berthur that seems sensible.  The OP still needs to confirm and clarify.  Perhaps the table columns should be labelled opponent 1 ad opponent 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
- LOOP Op1 over groups ( e.g. A,B,C,... )
   - LOOP Op2 over groups starting at Op1 + 1 ( e.g B,C, ... )
      - LOOP G over games
          - IF neither Op1 nor Op2 has played game G
              - ASSIGN Op1 v Op2 in game G
              - BREAK from LOOP G
```

Here is the C++ code

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class cMatchMaker
{
public:
    void ParseCommand(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        if (argc != 3)
            exit(1);
        groupCount = atoi(argv[1]);
        gameCount = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    void ConstructGroups()
    {
        for (int kg = 0; kg < groupCount; kg++)
        {
            std::string s({'A' + kg});
            vGroup.push_back(s);
            vGroupHasPlayed.push_back({});
        }
    }
    void ConstructGames()
    {
        for (int kg = 0; kg < gameCount; kg++)
        {
            vGame.push_back(std::to_string(kg + 1));
        }
    }

    void MakeMatches()
    {
        // loop over groups
        for (kop1 = 0; kop1 < groupCount; kop1++)
        {
            // loop over possible opponents
            for (kop2 = kop1 + 1; kop2 < groupCount; kop2++)
            {
                // loop over games
                for (auto &game : vGame)
                {
                    // check neither group has played game
                    if (!HasGameBeenPlayed(
                            game))
                    {
                        // we have a match!
                        DisplayMatch(
                            game);

                        // remember who played what
                        Remember(
                            game);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private:
    int groupCount, gameCount;
    std::vector<std::string> vGroup, vGame;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vGroupHasPlayed;
    int kop1, kop2;

    bool HasGameBeenPlayed(
        const std::string &game)
    {
        if (std::find(
                vGroupHasPlayed[kop1].begin(),
                vGroupHasPlayed[kop1].end(),
                game) != vGroupHasPlayed[kop1].end())
            return true;
        if (std::find(
                vGroupHasPlayed[kop2].begin(),
                vGroupHasPlayed[kop2].end(),
                game) != vGroupHasPlayed[kop2].end())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    void DisplayMatch(
        const std::string &game)
    {
        std::cout << " | " << vGroup[kop1]
                  << " | " << game << " | "
                  << vGroup[kop2] << " |\n";
    }

    void Remember(
        const std::string &game)
    {
        vGroupHasPlayed[kop1].push_back(game);
        vGroupHasPlayed[kop2].push_back(game);
    }
};

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cMatchMaker theMatchMaker;

    theMatchMaker.ParseCommand(argc, argv);
    theMatchMaker.ConstructGroups();
    theMatchMaker.ConstructGames();
    theMatchMaker.MakeMatches();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output for 7 and 6

| Op1 | Game | Op2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | B |
| A | 2 | C |
| A | 3 | D |
| A | 4 | E |
| A | 5 | F |
| A | 6 | G |
| B | 3 | C |
| B | 2 | D |
| B | 5 | E |
| B | 4 | F |
| C | 1 | D |
| C | 6 | E |
| C | 4 | G |
| D | 6 | F |
| D | 5 | G |
| E | 1 | F |
| E | 2 | G |
| F | 3 | G |

Comment: Thanks, but this answer is not correct. E.g.: Opponent B does never play game 6, opp C never plays game 5, ...

Comment: Yes.  Just as in your example where C never plays game 3, and plays game 2 twice.  My solution prevents an opponent playing the same game twice.